# LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: Usuario.autorizacoes, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my spring application, i implemented a custom AuthenticationProvider which made use from 
a Service to process my login requisition. The AuthenticationProvider is the follow:

https://github.com/klebermo/webapp_horario_livre/blob/master/src/com/horariolivre/security/CustomAuthenticationProvider.java

and my service class is that:

https://github.com/klebermo/webapp_horario_livre/blob/master/src/com/horariolivre/service/AuthenticationService.java

When I run the application, I am getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.horariolivre.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider com.horariolivre.security.SecurityConfig.authenticationProvider; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuthenticationProvider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.horariolivre.service.AuthenticationService com.horariolivre.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticationService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.horariolivre.service.AuthenticationService field com.horariolivre.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticationService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.horariolivre.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider com.horariolivre.security.SecurityConfig.authenticationProvider; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuthenticationProvider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.horariolivre.service.AuthenticationService com.horariolivre.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticationService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.horariolivre.service.AuthenticationService field com.horariolivre.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticationService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuthenticationProvider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.horariolivre.service.AuthenticationService com.horariolivre.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticationService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.horariolivre.service.AuthenticationService field com.horariolivre.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticationService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.horariolivre.service.AuthenticationService com.horariolivre.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticationService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.horariolivre.service.AuthenticationService field com.horariolivre.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticationService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.horariolivre.service.AuthenticationService field com.horariolivre.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticationService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:510)
    ... 37 more
```

Someone can point a direction to solve this problem?

===

Ok, I managed to solve the problem below adding the following option to my `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation:

```
(mode=AdviceMode.PROXY, proxyTargetClass=true)
```

Now I bumped in a new error, now in my AuthenticationService class, which code is:

https://github.com/klebermo/webapp_horario_livre/blob/master/src/com/horariolivre/service/AuthenticationService.java

the error is:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.horariolivre.entity.Usuario.autorizacoes, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.isEmpty(PersistentBag.java:249)
    at com.horariolivre.service.AuthenticationService.loadUserByUsername(AuthenticationService.java:35)
    at com.horariolivre.service.AuthenticationService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b8f020d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.horariolivre.service.AuthenticationService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a9c76951.loadUserByUsername(<generated>)
    at com.horariolivre.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CustomAuthenticationProvider.java:28)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

How I can solve this new error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solve all the question pointed in this topic. My final code in AuthenticationService is:

```
@Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Usuario account = accountDao.findByUsername(username);

        if(account == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user: " + username);
        }

        List<Autorizacoes> auth = account.getAutorizacoes();

        if(auth.isEmpty()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + username + " has no authorities");
        }

        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;
        boolean accountEnabled = true;

        return new User(account.getLogin(), account.getSenha(), accountEnabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, getAuthorities(account.getAutorizacoes()));
    }
```

In my Entity class, I declare the atribute `Autorizacoes` as:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "autorizacoes_usuario", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_usuario") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_autorizacoes") })
    //@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    public List<Autorizacoes> getAutorizacoes() {
        return this.autorizacoes;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Possibly the error is in your UserHome injection in your Service.

```
@Autowired
private UsuarioHome accountDao;
```

Comment: why? I don't understand.